# How to mount a flushed hard disk in Xubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, windows, live-usb, fdisk

I want to recover data from an internal hard disk with Windows Vista. I`m using a live CD of Xubuntu.

But when I write:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I obtain only the USB disk in which I have Xubuntu live.

How can I retrieve the path of the Windows hard disk and mount it?

I have tried with those commands:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-id/ata-TSSTcorp_CDDVDW_TS-L633A 
Mount failed: Error mounting: mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0

xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/ata-TSSTcorp_CDDVDW_TS-L633A 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov 11 12:31 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-TSSTcorp_CDDVDW_TS-L633A -> ../../sr0
```

I think the disk is `/dev/sr0` but the mount doesn`t work...

Comment: There is no other way. You may try something like lshw -C disk, but in line of principle if one fails, so should the other one.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae see my edits

Comment: I think sr0 is your cdrom, not your disk.

Comment: so there isn`t a solution?

Comment: Try `fdisk -l /dev/sda` or `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` or `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`...